# Density of power of some transcendental number

Tags: real-analysis, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

Let's note that where $\{x\}$ means fractional part of $x$. I am trying to figure out if $\{e^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{\pi^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are dense in $[0,1]$. In general do we know if fractional part of a power of a transcendental number is dense in $[0,1]$ or not ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think it's known that the numbers $\alpha>1$ such that $\alpha^n$ is not dense modulo one is a set of Lebesgue measure zero, but there are no individual numbers $\alpha$ for which it has been proved $\alpha^n$ is dense modulo one. In particular, I don't think anything is known for $\pi$ and $e$. A place to look is the book by Kuipers and Niederreiter.

Comment: Somewhat related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088110/equidistribution-modulo-1-of-certain-exponential-functions  More closely related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131018/sequences-equidistributed-modulo-1

Comment: Exactly, I know that we do not know if $\{e^n \}$ and $\{ \pi^n\}$ are equidistributed modulo $1$ or not but how about density? @Gerry Myerson

Comment: I think what's true for uniform distribution is also true (not for everything, but for $\alpha^n$) for density.

Comment: I know that uniform distribution $\Rightarrow$ density but I don't know if there is an equivalence in this case ($\alpha^n$). @GerryMyerson